# PrimeNG, Open accordion on Mouse hover event

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular 8 App and I am using PrimeNG 8. In one of my components, I have multiple accordions where I want to open accordion on the Mouse hover event. Please see the documentation here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion.

[image]

Can anyone please help how to achieve this on Mouse hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `activeIndex` property and JavaScript's `onmouseover` event. With the event you can set a public class's property, e.g. index.

```html
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="index">
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1" (mouseover)="index = 0">
        Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1" (mouseover)="index = 1">
        Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

And in your class you need the index as a global property.

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class XYComponent {
  index = 0;
}
```

Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1qyna).

EDIT: It actually works with the OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy.

Comment: sorry getting this error in console `TypeError: this._activeIndex.includes is not a function`.

Comment: See the updated answer. I've created a functional stackblitz.

Comment: Also, is there any way to activate [mutliple] property true for accordion ?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, it should work with `activeIndex` as well. In the documentation it is mentioned as *"Index of the active tab or an array of indexes to change selected tab programmatically."*. I would try to create a function with the index as parameter. Switch the public `index` an `indices` array and in the function check if the value exists. If yes, remove it, if no, add it.